# Typescript form reset() not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript1.4

I'm using typescript to reset a form but it's not working or typescript compiler (1.0.3 version) doesn't recognize reset() function.
Compiler gives Error

```
Build: Interface 'HTMLFormElement' incorrectly extends interface 'HTMLElement'. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.4\lib.d.ts
```

This is the typescript code

```
var resetForm =document.getElementById(dirtyFormID);
resetForm.reset();
```

When I copied above code to js file, it's working perfectly.

What's the reason for it?

Comment: An element typically doesn't have the `reset()` functionality, only the form elements. You are not explicitly saying you have a form element

Comment: `var resetForm: HTMLFormElement = <HTMLFormElement>document.getElementById(dirtyFormID);`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since the function `getElementById` returns a more generic type `HTMLElement` you need to assert the specific version manually :

```
var dirtyFormID = 'something';
var resetForm = <HTMLFormElement>document.getElementById(dirtyFormID);
resetForm.reset();
```

Comment: it's not at all working, getting a error " resetForm.reset is not a function"

Answer (score 2):

With typescript.

to avoid Google Chrome Error  "resetForm.reset is not a function", I specified the type of my button element, "reset" in my HTML code. Having specified a:

```
type = 'reset'
```

make my function works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `document.getElementById` returns `HTMLElement` (like already said here). 
You should cast your `HTMLElement` to `HTMLFormElement`

The casting should be like this:

```
var resetForm:HTMLFormElement;
resetForm= <HTMLFormElement>document.getElementById('your form id');
if(resetForm)
    resetForm.reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Amos Dabush answer VSCode ofered me to use event.target as HTMLFormElement

```
const submitHandler = (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    const resetForm = e.target as HTMLFormElement;
    resetForm.reset();
  };
```

And it works for me like a charm having

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => submitHandler(e)}>
```